# Issue with monorepo, craco and eslint

Tags: eslint, monorepo, craco

I'm having some issue with eslint in a monorepo ( Yarn3 ) and CRACO.
I have a monorepo with the classic `apps/*` and `packages/*` structure:

```
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*",
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "craco-alias": "^3.0.1"
     ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     ...
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.3"
}
```

I've a `dashboard` app package and I start it using `craco start` but I've my `craco.config.js` file in the root of the monorepo and I link it using `"cracoConfig": "../../craco.config.js"` in the dashboard package.json.

In the `craco.config.js` I enable the `.eslintrjs using

```
eslint: {
    mode: "file",
  },
```

It kinda "works" but it just do the lint checks for the `dashboard` package and not for all the other packages. But if I run `eslint .` in the terminal it do the checks for all the packages without issue.

Any idea on how I can fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I think all the other packages installed inside the dashboard is not being linted. Is that what you are facing?